# crypt function PHP showing the salt in plain form

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

I'm using crypt function to create the hash from the string, but when used the salt parameter it's showing the salt parameter in plain form, I know the salt parameter is optional we can exclude that but what is the way to make the salt to not show in the plain form in the hashed string.
Example code

```
echo crypt('something','$5$rounds=5000$anexamplestring$');
```

Output for this code is

```
$5$rounds=5000$anexamplestring$YuRqx9rDLGE1wLc9Bp01/DetFvo6S7Bphn6TgGViCD8
```

Here the output starting string is same as the crypt function that looks awkward, is there any way around to fix this, or this is the default behavior?

Comment: Of course this is default behavior. To _verify_ the original text value against the stored hash next time, the salt that was used needs to be available again, otherwise that would not work in the first place.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification: _“A password hash requires the use of a large random, **non-secret** salt value which **can be stored with the password hash**. The salt randomizes the output of the password hash, making it impossible for an adversary to store tables of passwords and precomputed hash values to which the password hash digest can be compared.”_

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can't decrypt it without salt, it will be in the hash.

I do this if you need to encrypt something, then you need openssl and the string can be long, but each time a new one and you can't pick it up without a key.

```
function get_encrypt($str = false, $key = false)
{
    if (!is_string($str)) {
        return false;
    }

    $key = !empty($key) ?: 'b7^FV7867&f)vd6567';

    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($str, $cipher, $key, $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary = true);
    $encrypttext = base64_encode($iv . $hmac . $ciphertext_raw);

    return ($encrypttext);
}


function get_decrypt($str = false, $key = false)
{
    $key = !empty($key) ?: 'b7^FV7867&f)vd6567';

    $c = base64_decode($str);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len = 32);
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen + $sha2len);
    $decrypttext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary = true);
    if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
        return ($decrypttext);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$str = get_encrypt('something'); // out: ccxCvYCQrsCDC8LA1jrxh3OP38KzLXk5NLxIaSH2W7oDsqUSi3gsmZBq8hnVwuAfCZwt3M1lJhHjFAArHXlrcA==

get_decrypt($str); // out: something
```

Comment: note that [`crypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) is for hashing passwords.  the above just seems to be a copy/paste of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php (and hence should be attributed as such) and is solving a different problem